# Can we implement method overloading in web service class?

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, apache-axis

I would like to implement method overloading in the Java web service class as follows:

```
public String myMethod(User user)
{
    // My code
} 

public String myMethod(User[] user)
{
    for(int i=0; i<user.length; i++)
    {
        myMethod(user[i]);
    }
}
```

If I forward a single `User` object to `myMethod()`, it should trigger the first method and if I send an array of `User`s, it should trigger the second method.

In the WSDL file it shows only a single method. However, if I try to call `@WebMethod(operationName="")` for both calls, I am unable to generate the WSDL file.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to overload a webservice, and even if it is, it's certainly not good practice

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Operation overloading is **not** allowed for web services.
It is explicitely prohibited in [WS-BP](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.0-2004-04-16.html) and [WSDL 1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-wsdl12-20020709/) also disallows it.
Even if you found a stack that has some support for this I would recommend **not** to follow this approach.
Overloading is an `OO` concept. Don't try to apply them to `Service Oriented` paradigm

Comment: Overloading isn't an OO concept and it doesn't have any relation with OO, for example, the C language is a procedural/structured language and it offers functions overloading.

Answer (score 5):

Overloading the web service methods is not difficult. With Axis 1.4 at least it is fairly simple. If there are two overloaded methods in the service like below:

```
public String myMethod(String firstName, String lastName) throws RemoteException
public String myMethod(String name) throws RemoteException
```

Then a request like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/services/testService?method=myMethod&name=<name>
```

will invoke the second method.

And a request like this one:

```
http://localhost:8080//services/testService?method=myMethod&firstName=<first_name>&lastName=<last_name>
```

will invoke the first method.

The resolution is done by Axis.

Comment: +1, good info. Though I worked with Axis for a good while, I didn't know Axis could do that. I would never go about it this way since it is not "kosher" web service design, but it is good to know if I ever run into a corner case where I must implement such a thing.