# update existing jax -ws service method parameter

Tags: web-services, dynamic, parameters, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS service running with a method, for ex:

```
        calculate(int a, int b) .
```

Now I want to add a new parameter to this method

```
        calculate(int a, int b, int c)
```

without disturbing the current clients whoever consuming the first service method, and both methods should have the same name.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method overloading for service calls is not encouraged even though few tools may allow you to do so.  Pls Refer. [Can we implement method overloading in web service class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320006/can-we-implement-method-overloading-in-web-service-class).  When the wsdl changes anyway your client have to take new stubs.  So better take the latest signature code.  Have a default value for 3rd parameter so that old clients can send the default value.

Comment: my existing client may not be ready to change his access logic.These changes are for the new clients only,So i thought if any possibility to overload the methods.

Comment: You should use a different method name.  maybe calculate_new or if you still want the name to be calculate it should be in different namespace.  Once the old clients are ready to upgrade they will recode to use the name name.