# Error when deploying web app on Glassfish

Tags: java, exception, glassfish

I'm using Eclipse + Glassfish 4.0

When I deploying a simple project, following error appears :

```
cannot Deploy Testmart 

deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading 
the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Servlet web service endpoint '' failure. Please see server.log for more details.
```

EDIT :

**ProductCatalog.java** Class :

```
import org.hamed.train.service.ProductServiceImp;

@WebService
public class ProductCatalog {
    ProductServiceImp productService = new ProductServiceImp();
    @WebMethod
    public List<String> getProducts() {
        return productService.getProductCategories();
    }
    public List<String> getProducts(String category) {
        return productService.getProducts(category);
    }
}
```

`system.log` content :
http://txs.io/B7P

Comment: paste the stack trace from `server.log`

Comment: What's the servlet code (especially `@WebServlet` annotation) and deployment descriptor?

Comment: I did not used `@WebServlet` any where! Should I?

Comment: I was intrigued by the `Servlet web service endpoint '' failure.` that you had a servlet, But I could be wrong of course. Maybe the code you posted is not the one giving you problems, but its hard to know because the string which could help identify the faulty code is empty. `@WebService` has a few properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jws/WebService.html Try setting them like `name="a", serviceName="b", ...`, then if a letter appears in the log, you know the annotation was the culprit and which property was missing.

Comment: Is this a problem with [method overloading in web services](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10320175/2549021)?

Comment: @SillyFreak@AKS Thank you for reply but the problem does not solved. I'm following [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLzM92ZnisY) on Youtube. It works fine for training provider but doesn't for me.

Comment: the log says `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class org.hamed.train.jaxws.GetProducts do not have a property of the name arg0`, the error seems to be in another class...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to @Silly Freak's comment, I found the answer.

These two method should not have the same name :

**ProductCatalog.java**

```
public List<String> getProducts() {
        return productService.getProductCategories();
    }

public List<String> getProducts(String category) {
        return productService.getProducts(category);
    }
```

**Solution:**

I changed first method name to something else and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was, I missed to include the no arguments constructor or "Product" class. It worked when I included the no argument constructor.

Note: JAXB requires no arg constructor to instantiate the object.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, the **glassfish** was on Linux environment. check your `$JAVA_HOME` it should be set in to jdk

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_55

/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin # echo $JAVA_HOME

/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_55
```

then problem was solved..

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with eclipse galileo, and I was sure that it was related to my hibernate mapping, because publishing process started to fail when I made a new mapping to a table using an HBM file, mapping was proper in HBM file but the problem was with my DAO class.

Sample code of my DAO class :-

```
public class MyDAO
{
     private int id;
     private int name;
     private boolean isActive;

     public int getId() {
        return id;
     }
     public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
     }
     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
     }
     public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
     }
     public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
     }
}
```

You can see the getters and setters of boolean variable is different from the other two variables (all the getters and setters were developed by eclipse itself). Now viewing from framework perspective, it will take an attribute name, change its first character to uppercase and attach a get or set as a prefix to invoke the attribute's getter and setter. So in the case of boolean attribute it will go wrong.

So when I changed the existing getters and setters to default form like `getIsActive()` and `setIsActive()`, it was published properly.