# Can a WSDL file contain overloading methods in Java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have two overloaded methods within a java web service class.  After I deployed it onto Weblogic 10, I only see the first one in the WSDL file.  Is there a way that both methods can be included in the WSDL file?  Thanks.

```
 public class User
 {
     public getUserName();
     public getUserName(String school);
 }
```

Comment: I don't think WSDL allows for multiple services with the same name.

Comment: This has already been answered on Stack Overflow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320006/can-we-implement-method-overloading-in-web-service-class

Comment: Is that the actual code you are using, i.e. you're not using any `@WebService` or `@WebMethod` annotations? How is the WSDL generated, then?